# Unable to authenticate mongodb remotely

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, authentication, heroku, digital-ocean

I am unable to authenticate mongodb remotely. I'm running MongoDB 3.0.0 provided by the DigitalOcean One-Click installer, and I can't seem to set up authentication properly.

I have 1 database called wbio_production. I followed mongodb docs tutorials as best as I could. When I execute:

```
> db.auth("siteUserAdmin","MYPASSWORD")
1
> db.getUsers()
```

The output of that is:

```
{
    "_id" : "admin.siteUserAdmin",
    "user" : "siteUserAdmin",
    "db" : "admin",
    "roles" : [
        {
            "role" : "userAdminAnyDatabase",
            "db" : "admin"
        }
    ]
}
```

And when I switch to the wbio_production database and perform the same getUsers():

```
> use wbio_production
switched to db wbio_production
> db.getUsers()
[
    {
        "_id" : "wbio_production.herokuUser",
        "user" : "herokuUser",
        "db" : "wbio_production",
        "roles" : [
            {
                "role" : "userAdmin",
                "db" : "wbio_production"
            },
            {
                "role" : "readWrite",
                "db" : "wbio_production"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

When I fill out the connection form in Robomongo however, it cannot successfully connect to the database. Authorization always fails, however it does successfully connect to the database.

I have tried the following combinations of using the users above:

1. DB: Admin, User: siteUserAdmin
2. DB: Admin, User: herokuUser
3. DB: wbio_production, User: siteUserAdmin
4. DB: wbio_production, User: herokuUser

All of them wind up with some output coming back in the heroku logs similar:

> failed with error 13: "not authorized for query on
>   wbio_production.mongoid_forums_forums"

I have tried reinstalling mongodb, recreating users based off different tutorials, and just trying different peoples explanations. I've spent about 5 hours now looking for a solution to my issue, and now I must turn to SO for your advice. I'm sure this is a simple error on my part that I am not understanding from the docs or something I am continuously missing in the set up.

What must I do to get a secured and functional MongoDB server? Thanks!

Comment: How are you authenticating the user when you connect to mongo?

Comment: A quick question, can I assume you are connecting via ssh to a mongo shell to execute your above mongo? If so, the fault may lie in robomongo, as I found this on their site: Note: We are working on an update with MongoDB 3.0 compatibility for the upcoming Robomongo 0.9.x release series. If this is the case I would recommend using the mongo shell to do what you need to and setting up mms (https://mms.mongodb.com/) I believe it's free to give an oversight on your instance. NewRelic also has free plugins to do this.

Comment: You should definitely try connecting from the mongo shell so you have fewer layers between you and the database.

Comment: Have you verified the config in mongod.config file?

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure mongod with its binding so clients can connect remotely.

```
bind_ip = 0.0.0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Robomongo authentication does not work with MongoDB 3+. I recommend switching over to MongoChef.  http://3t.io/mongochef/.  I highly recommend it, as it contains MANY more capabilities than Robomongo does.

**Another thing to keep in the back of your mind...**

If you are also using Mongoid, it is currently undergoing a large rewrite. Mongoid 5 will drop Moped https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/announcing-ruby-driver-20-rewrite.

Take a look at my other answer on what to do if you are using Mongoid 4 with MongoDB 3+.  [Rails Mongoid fails to authenticate - failed with error 13: "not authorized for query on my_db.my_collection"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29875839/rails-mongoid-fails-to-authenticate-failed-with-error-13-not-authorized-for/30875477#30875477)